# Using getmessagetime with peekmessage instead of getmessage

Tags: winapi

I need to modify an application and the changes involve using the time of events as they are posted to the window message loop. Anyway, long story short, I'm using `getmessagetime` in the window message handler to obtain the time of messages. It seems to work fine but the documentation of `getmessagetime` explicitly states it will return the `msg.time` parameter if the message loop runs with `getmessage` but says nothing if it runs with `peekmessage(...,pm_remove)` as is the case of this application.

So the question is, is `getmessagetime` reliable if the application's message loop runs with `peekmessage(...,pm_remove)` or should I ask the client for permission to modify the message loop for a `peekmessage(...,pm_no_remove)+getmessage` combo? Or in other words, is the internal value read by `getmessagetime` set by `getmessage` or by `dispatchmessage`?

Reason why I can't simply ask to change the message loop to keep the msg.time parameter is that if the user is resizing the window, windows uses an internal message loop and not the application's message loop so the `msg.time` parameter would not be set, hence having to use `getmessagetime` to guarantee a reliable time.

Comment: Definitely not DispatchMessage.  You are going to have to call Microsoft if you want a guarantee.  I'd be very surprised if they tell you no.

Comment: Yeah it seems ok but its gonna look bad if when this contract is over a problem pops up about this. I'll tell my client to evaluate calling MS since otherwise their company policy is regression testing on all changed components, which is the reason i'm trying to change as few components as possible, and they'll have to decide which option is less expensive for them.

Comment: Client accepted changing the peekmessage loop to add a getmessage, but for future reference if anyone ever happens by here with a search, after a huge number of automated tests it seemed like both getmessage/peekmessage(pm_remove) set the value read by getmessagetime or that dispatchmessage does it, or in other words, getmessagetime looks like it should always work with a peekmessage(pm_remove) message loop. Should still get final confirmation by MS for production code in case of weird edge cases.